# which one to select (pg_basebackup or pg_dumpall )when migrating 9.3 to 9.4 postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating my postgres 9.3 to 9.4 and for that i need to take backup of existing DB, so I am confused in 2 pg_basebackup and pg_dumpall.

I am new to postgres, and help or suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: I think the versions have to match exactly to be able to restore from a physical backup (pg_basebackup), so for migrations across versions you have to do a logical backup (pg_dumpall).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_basebackup` won't work, since 9.4 can't start from a 9.3 data directory.

Your options are:

- `pg_dumpall`. Simplest.
- `pg_upgrade`. Lowest downtime, but trickier.
- `pg_dumpall --globals-only`, then `pg_dump -Fc` each database and restore with `psql` for the globals then `pg_restore` for each database. This approach is more flexible, and is what I generally use for backups.